# Python script from PHP not running when importing a certain library

Tags: php, python

I m running a simple pyton script from php. The python script uses this library  (https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition). This library is imported by using 
`import face_recognition`. The problem is when I include this statement in python I get no output in php . Other python scripts without  `import face_recognition` run fine.
 I've tried

```
$last_line = system('python test.py ', $retval);

$cmd_modified = $cmd . " >/dev/null & echo \$!";
$cmd_output = NULL; // this will be an array of output
$cmd_return_value = NULL; // this will be the return value of the 

exec($cmd_modified, $cmd_output, $cmd_return_value);
echo "exec has completed</br>";
echo "output:<br>" . print_r($cmd_output, TRUE) . "<br>";
echo "return value: " .  $cmd_return_value ;
```

I get
     output:
     Array ( [0] => 17424 ) 
return value: 0

The script takes 5 seconds to complete in terminal but i've added   `ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);` to prevent timing php out

How should i run this??

Comment: try './python_test.py` or try to use it's full address such as '/usr/bin/python test.py'

Comment: What is the output, if you run your python script from shell?

Comment: @Daniel I get '2' (basically i get an output) thats not true when using the import statement .I get nothing in that case

Comment: @Forbs no success

Comment: Try running it from the bash shell